# Reference request – a priori estimate – mixed boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am interested in finding references regarding estimates of the form
$$ \| D^2 u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C(\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|g\|_{S} )$$
where $\|D^2 u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \sum\limits_{i,j \in \{1,2\}} \int_{\Omega}(\partial_{x_i x_j}u)^2$ and
$$ \begin{cases}
-\Delta u = f & \text{ in }\Omega \\
u = 0 & \text{ on } \Gamma_D \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = g & \text{ on } \Gamma_N
\end{cases} $$
and $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ is polygonal (bounded, convex) such that the solution $u$ belongs to $H^2(\Omega)$ (in particular $g$ is regular enough). The space $S$ for $g$ is $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_N)$ (but I am interested in other options if available). The boundaries $\Gamma_D, \Gamma_N$ are both non-void and make a partition for $\partial\Omega$.

I was able to find in the book of Grisvard (*Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains*) a similar result when $g\equiv 0$. However, I could not find this precise estimate for the non-homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions.

> Can you point me to a reference that contains proofs of such estimates? In particular, I am interested in finding precisely the constant $C$ (if possible).

Comment: In Grisvard's book, mixed boundary conditions is covered, as he considers a general boundary condition operator..

Comment: Since your domain is convex, it is worth trying to do the calculation by hand, using Morawetz multipliers (testing against $\chi \cdot Du$ where $\chi$ is an extension of the normal vector into the interior) to check if you can't get simply $C=1$.

Comment: @username: Thank you for your suggestions. Indeed, in Grisvard's book, there is a section on a priori estimates, where such  kind of estimates is presented. However, it is in a very general setting, and in the case of the Laplacian, I thought there may be a more direct reference where the computations are more straightforward. I will try your second suggestion.

Comment: @username: it turns out it is possible to obtain an estimate by integrating by parts by hand. It is weird that I couldn't find any explicit references regarding this.